# Kotlin - Factory class with properties issues

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to write factory class in Kotlin. In Java:

```
public class MyFactory {
   private static MyFactory instance = null;
   private Properties props = null;
   private FirstClass firstInstance = null;
   private SecondClass secondInstance = null;

   private MyFactory() {
     props = new Properties();
     try {
       props.load(new FileInputStream("path/to/config"));

       String firstClass = props.getProperty(“first.class”);
       String secondClass = props.getProperty(“second.class”);
       firstInstance = (FirstClass) Class.forName(firstClass).newInstance();
       secondInstance = (SecondClass) Class.forName(secondClass).newInstance();
     } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
     }
  }
  static {
    instance = new MyFactory();
  }
  public static MyFactory getInstance() {
    return instance;
  }

  public FirstClass getFirstClass() {
    return firstInstance;
  }

  public SecondClass getSecondClass() {
    return secondInstance;
  }

}
```

And I encountered few issues trying to rewrite this in Kotlin.
I tried to generate code first with Java converter on try.kotlinlang.org. The result is:

```
class MyFactory private constructor() {
  private var props: Properties? = null

  private var firstInstance: FirstClass? = null
  private var secondInstance: SecondClass? = null

  init {
      try {
          props!!.load(FileInputStream("path/to/conf"))

          val firstClass = props!!.getProperty("prop")
          val secondClass = props!!.getProperty("prop")

          firstInstance = Class.forName(firstClass).newInstance() as FirstClass
          secondInstance = Class.forName(secondClass).newInstance() as SecondClass
      } catch (ex: Exception) {
          ex.printStackTrace()
      }
  }

  companion object {
      var instance: MyFactory? = null

      init{
          instance = MyFactory()
     }
   }
}
```

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 15, and it says that this class don't have `getInstance()` method, but when I try to implement it it says:

```
  Platform declaration clash: The following declarations have the same JVM signature:
fun <get-instance>(): my.package.MyFactory?
fun getInstance(): my.package.MyFactory?
```

As I remember, getters are auto-implemented only in data classes.
Can someone clarify this situation or maybe tell me the right way how to implement this?
UPDATE:
I make use of this class in Kotlin by refering to properties itself, ex. MyFactory.instance!!.firstInstance, but it feels wrong to do it this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The explanation is the following:

Kotlin compiler creates getters and setters for all properties, but they are visible only in Java. In Kotlin, properties are idiomatic, and they are even [generated from Java getter and setter pair](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#getters-and-setters) when you use Java classes.

Thus declaring a method `getInstance` indeed clashes with the [auto-generated getter that will be visible in Java code](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#properties).

If you need custom getter behaviour please use getter syntax:

```
var instance: MyFactory? = null
get() {
    /* do something */
    return field
}
```

In this example `field` is a soft keyword and means backing field for the property.

It is documented [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#getters-and-setters).

By the way, [object declaration](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-declarations) seems to fit your case well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so MyFactory.instance is basically valid get-accessor "method" ?

Comment: @IlyaPuzanov, you're welcome. Yes, Kotlin compiler will generate `MyFactory.getInstance()` for Java, and in Kotlin `MyFactory.instance` is already *getting* the property value.